# Can the tangent line replace the function when calculating a limit when $x\to a$ and $a$ is the $x$-coordinate of the tangency point?

Tags: limits

If you have a function $f$, differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$, such that $y= -3x+2$ is tangent to its graph at $x=2$.

Can you replace $f(x)$ by $-3x+2$ when you are calculating the following limit?

$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \dfrac{f(x)+4}{x^2-4}$

My opinion is: no, because they are not the same thing. But it works and I can't find an example where it doesn't work. Anyone has one?

By the way, what I find formally correct is something like this:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \dfrac{f(x)+4}{x^2-4} = \underbrace{\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \dfrac{f(x)-(\color{red}{\overbrace{\color{black}{-4}}^{f(2)}})}{x-2}}_{f'(2)} \times \lim\limits_{x \to 2} \dfrac{1}{x+2} = -3\times \dfrac{1}{4} = -\dfrac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this replacement would not be rigourous. What you can do instead is apply the definition of $f'(2)$ you recalled, and which can be reworded as
$$\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=f'(2)+\varepsilon(x)\text{ whith }\lim_{x\to2}\varepsilon(x)=0,$$
i.e. replace $f(x)$ with
$$f(2)+(x-2)f'(2)+(x-2)\varepsilon(x)=-3x+2+(x-2)\varepsilon(x).$$
This way, as $x\to2,$
$$\frac{f(x)+4}{x^2-4}=\frac{-3x+6+(x-2)\varepsilon(x)}{x^2-4}=\frac{-3+\varepsilon(x)}{x+2}\to-\frac34.$$

This is more than a matter of rigor. A rough replacement of $f(x)$ by its linear approximation can lead to wrong results. Take for instance $f(x)=\cos x$ and look at $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-1}{x^2}.$ If you replace $f(x)$ with $f(0)+xf'(0)=1+0x=1,$ the numerator becomes $0$ and you find a limit equal to $0,$ whereas the correct result is $-\frac12.$

Comment: To emphasize: the validity of this replacement is in some contexts the very definition of the derivative, but depending where you are on your mathematical journey you may have to wait a while before you see that definition in practice.

Comment: would you say it is only a matter of rigour or is it possible to find an example where it doesn't work?